# How to disable onclick function from child selector using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

How can i make sure that onclick events only fires by clicking on **td** not on the span ?

```
<td style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="getDetails(13,3)">
   <span class="responsiveExpander"></span>
    TEST
</td>


function getDetails(table_id,id)
{
   alert(table_id + id);
}
```

Comment: Also check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add an event listener to the inner child and cancel the propagation of the event.

In plain JS something like

```
document.getElementById('inner').addEventListner('click',function (e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

is sufficient. Note that [jQuery provides the same facility](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$(".inner-div").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

or

```
$(".inner-inner").on('click',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to prevent clicks on all sub-elements, pass the `event` to `getDetails` and have it see if `event.currentTarget` is the same as `event.target`.

```js
function getDetails(event, table_id, id) {
   if (event.currentTarget !== event.target) {
     return; // clicked a sub-element
   }
   alert(table_id + id);
}
```

```css
span {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="getDetails(event, 13,3)">
   <span class="responsiveExpander">SHOULD NOT ALERT</span>
    TEST
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow,what a nice way to handle this sort of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows;

```js
data.addEventListener("click", function(e){
                                 e.target === this && console.log("td clicked");
                               });
```

```css
td {border: red solid 2px;}
span{color: white; background-color: black}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="data" style="cursor: pointer">
      <span>SPAN:</span> TEST
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```